# how to enable wsl to respond to broadcast ping request

Tags: linux, networking, network-programming, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-networking

I was using WSL to run ROS commands, and at a point i had to enable system to respond to broadcast icmp requests (for a multi master kind of a setup) i.e. on linux i had to make sure

> cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts

returns 0. but WSL does not contain such a file, so i was thinking of enabling it on windows. All the sources i have gone through suggest me to add a rule to firewall but my system is not responding to broadcast ping even when my system's firewall is turned off(domain, private and public have been turned off same with my buddy who is no the same network). i am using an android phone's mobile hotspot to check this.

it would be great if someone could help me on this.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I asked something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62189602/how-to-enable-icmp-service-in-windows)

I don't know how to do it purely on WSL. But on windows you have to start the "TCPSVCS.EXE" process. located on System32