# How to enable ICMP service in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-networking

It is enabled by default, however I can't tell it's not enabled, because

1. Firewall is disabled
2. ping 127.0.0.1 times out.
   I get

[image: Internet seems to work perfectly tho]

If you google for "enable icmp in windows", all you get is how to open a port on the firewall, but that assumes that your icmp daemon/service is enabled, but how do you enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process that listens to port 7 to ICMP echo requests is called TCPSVCS.EXE

<s>You can try calling "C:\Windows\System32\TCPSVCS.EXE" to see if it works and starts listening to ICMP echo requests.</s>

The service that start this process is called simptcp, just enable it.

[image: TCPSVCS.EXE]

Comment: TCP/UDP echo is unrelated to ICMP_ECHO (except both have 'echo' in the name).